# Circle overlay in Google Map V3 API js

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to insert this circle on a google map, the map displays fine by including the following js file in the header;

```
/**
       * Called on the intiial page load.
       */
      function initialize() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.272213,-5.054973);
        var options = {
          'zoom': 9,
          'center': latLng,
          'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            options);

      }

      // Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But when i add the following to include the circle it breaks and doesn't load;

```
 /**
       * Called on the intiial page load.
       */
      function initialize() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.272213,-5.054973);
        var options = {
          'zoom': 9,
          'center': latLng,
          'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            options);

        // Add a Circle overlay to the map.
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.272213,-5.054973),
            fillColor: #00FF00,
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeColor: #00FF00,
            strokeOpacity: 0.4,
            strokeWeight: 2
            });
            circle.setRadius(18362.55489862987);

      }

      // Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

If somebody could point out where im going wrong please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your listener code to this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'onload', initialize());
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pVh3b/1/

Comment: Thanks, This clearly works however it still wont load on my wordpress website using the same code, maybe there is a js conflict?

Comment: I guess it could be a conflict.  I have not worked with Wordpress at all.  You may want to ask a separate question with the relevant code.

Comment: This is wrong answer, what this does is run the initialize immediately, and the whole line could be reduced to `initialize()` - why it works is probably the code was already in the load event. Correct way to is to do it without parenthesis, just like it was, and is in the [Hello World](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Don't call setRadius, just specify radius as a parameter of the circle options.  Also given that you've already got a latlng object created with the same coordinates as the center of the circle, just reuse that.

```
 var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            center: latLng,
            fillColor: #00FF00,
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeColor: #00FF00,
            strokeOpacity: 0.4,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            radius: 18362.55489862987
 });
```