# Unable to view map circle overlay results in Google JS API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I have been testing this in the Google Code Playground before I try to implement anything further.

This simply places a map marker on the map and produces a circle overlay with it by a radius given in miles. However, I am still unable to get this to work.

It seems to break on the circle overlay creation. I have been searching for a solution but everything I have tried so far either breaks (the map does not display) or gives me no result (no circle overlay).

Note: I came across a similar question [question:] [Circle overlay in Google Map V3 API js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712861/circle-overlay-in-google-map-v3-api-js) .
I tried this solution but it did not work.

```
function initialize()
{
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
  {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(30.6957, -88.1813), 13);


    var latlng = new GLatLng(30.6957, -88.1813);
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(latlng));

    var draw_circle = null;

    function Draw_Circle(Miles)
    { 
      Miles *= 1600;

      if (draw_circle != null)
      {
        draw_circle.setMap(null);
      }

      draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: latlng,
        radius: Miles,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
      });  
    }

    Draw_Circle(15);
  }
 }
```

Thank you again in advance.

EDIT: Now that I have been informed that I was mixing API Versions. I came up with the following:

```
var latLng;

function initialize() {
  var map;
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.6957, -88.1813),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.6957, -88.1813);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map
    });

  var draw_circle = null;

  function Draw_Circle(Miles)     
  {        
    Miles *= 1600;        
    if (draw_circle != null)       
    {         
      draw_circle.setMap(null);       
    }       

    draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({         
      center: latlng,         
      radius: Miles,         
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",         
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,         
      strokeWeight: 2,         
      fillColor: "#FF0000",         
      fillOpacity: 0.35,         
      map: map       
     });

  }      

  Draw_Circle(15);
}
```

I am ALMOST there... Now, I don't have any error messages from the debugger to signify what is wrong with my circle overlay.

Comment: This looks like a mix of V2 and V3. which api are you referencing?

Comment: That I did not know. I should only be using Version 3. The example I got the function from was supposed to be V3.

Comment: are you getting any errors in your [console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)? (like GMap2 undefined)

Comment: Ah, this I didn't see before. It seems it isn't registering Circle as a constructor. More than likely due to the mix of Version 2 and 3 code. Oddly, I used the same examples in Code Playground.

Comment: what is the issue now? any errors?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error messages in the debugger this time.

Comment: is the map being displayed?

Comment: Yes, the map and marker are being displayed as normal on the map. However, overlay is still not appearing to be visible. Also, the debugger did not flag any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1**: You are using [Google Maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) and [Google Maps API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) together.

**Issue 2**: In the following code

```
.....
draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({         
  center: latlng,   
  .....
```

The Error thrown is `ReferenceError: latlng is not defined`.

If you replace `latlng` with `latLng`, the script will work as expected.

Comment: I found a solution to it. I manipulated the example given by Google and was able to get the method to work. I have to wait to post the solution though. Thank you for you help - I wouldn't have made it this far without it.

Comment: If you replace the 'latlng' with 'latLng' your solution will work.